How to detect users using @twa-dev/sdk for a TMA (Telegram Mini App)?
I want to create a TMA (Telegram Mini App) using @twa-dev/sdk. I don't any auth in the app but I need to pass a something like Telegram ID, etc. to my API endpoint to save/retrieve user related data in/from database.
Is there any property in @twa-dev/sdk to implement this?
